# IO Exception: Connection Reset Error from jvm to db

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection

I have two application servers distinctly located in two different data centers, running the application in active-active mode. The application db is also hosted between the same two data center in active-passive mode. I am receiving connection reset errors from my application server which is on the other datacenter, when connecting to the DB. These connection reset errors are intermittent and no ORA/Java exception codes are provided with it. ht e datacenter diagram is provided here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGKPU.png)

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Io exception: Connection reset

Comment: If you're only seeing it in the cross-DC traffic then there's probably a firewall killing what it thinks is an idle or too-old connection. The reset is happening when you try to use a (pooled?) connection and it finds that it's dead, and has to start a replacement. You might need to talk to your network people to find out if they can see it being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

A network appliance somewhere between your app server and the Database may kill the socket based on inactivity. This happens with large connection pools where all connections aren't used frequently. It could be resolved by turning keep_alive on all the JDBC connections. To do so set the JDBC property "`oracle.net.keepAlive`" to "`true`".